# Unique ID when google sign in using Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have created an app that has multiple sign-in options such as email and password or with google account.

Every time a user is signing in, I save some data about it such as account creating data, nickname and so on.

I store it in my Firebase database in the following path:

Users (collection) -> auth.getuid (document with unique id) -> UserData (collection) ->some fields

So when I sign in using email and password and I use to authenticate, I can get a unique id by using `auth.getid`. In that way I make sure there won't be 2 same documents for different users.

Now, if I use google sign in by using the following:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RequestSignInCode){

        GoogleSignInResult googleSignInResult = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);

        if (googleSignInResult.isSuccess()){

            GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = googleSignInResult.getSignInAccount();
            FirebaseUserAuth(googleSignInAccount);

            FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

            Map<String, Object> user = new HashMap<>();
            user.put("username", googleSignInAccount.getEmail());
            user.put("email",googleSignInAccount.getEmail());
            user.put("dateCreated", FieldValue.serverTimestamp());

            db.collection( "Users" ).document(auth.getUid()).collection( "UserData" ).add( user );

            Intent intent = new Intent( SignInActivity.this, DiscoverActivity.class );
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }

    }
}
```

Is there anything equivalent to auth.getuid when using google sign-in so I could create a unique document for that user?

Or even better, can I still somehow use auth.getID? because if in all of my code when I used email + password sign-in I could query by using `auth.getuid`, now I won't be able and will need to create a separate query based on `some google.id`?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Any Firebase Authentication user has a UID, that you can use to identify that user. It doesn't matter what provider they signed in with (email/password, google, or any other). This UID will even work when you allow the same user to sign with different providers, and you [link those accounts](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But does it mean that I still can use the line of auth.getUid()? Because it seems like it does not return any value when I use it from FirebaseUserAuth. What I mean is that in my signin activity Ihave both methods. then in the next activity I useauth.getuid to find a document. However when I sign in with google, it does not find this auth.getuid.

Comment: The `FirebaseUserAuth` class does not appear in the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth), so it's hard for me to say what it does. But if you sign in to Firebase Authentication with the Google provider as shown [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin), you will be able to get the UID of that user from `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()`.

Comment: So is there any more recommend way to get uid that will fit all cases? because I tried auth.getuid but according to your answer maybe .getCurrentUser.getUid is better way

Comment: If you want us to be able to help better, make sure that the code in your question has enough context, so that we can reasonably reproduce the problem. I have no idea what your `auth` variable refers to, so can't tell what it returns and how that relates to the Firebase UID which you get with `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()`.